# Terraform - yamlencode() is returning YAML in backwards format

Tags: yaml, terraform

Everytime I run this yamldecode function to create a yaml file in a github repository, the format comes out backwards:

Output:

```
      "framework": "N/A"
      "language": "Terraform"
      "lifecycle": "generally_available"
      "owner": "someone"
      "repositories":
        "display_name": "miscellaneous-infrastructure"
        "name": "someone/miscellaneous-infrastructure"
        "path": "/"
        "provider": "github"
      "serivce":
        "aliases":
        - "N/A"
        "description": "Repository for the hardware team's miscellaneous infrastructure."
        "name": "miscellaneous-infrastructure"
        "product": "hardware"
      "tier": "tier_3"
      "version": 1
```

yaml.tf:

```
locals {
  yaml = {
    version : 1,
    serivce : {
      name : "${var.serivce_name}",
      description : "${var.description}",
      product : "${var.product_name}",
      aliases : "${var.aliases}"
    },

    owner : var.organization,
    lifecycle : var.serivce_lifecycle,
    tier : var.tier,
    language: var.language,
    framework: var.framework,

    repositories : {
      name : "${var.organization}/${var.name}",
      path: "/"
      provider: "github",
      display_name : "${var.serivce_name}"
    }
  }
```

}

github-file.tf:

```
resource "github_repository_file" "opslevel" {
  repository          = github_repository.repository.name
  file                = "yaml.yml"
  content             = yamlencode(local.yaml)

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      content
    ]
  }

  depends_on = [
    github_repository.repository,
    github_team.reviewers_team
  ]
}
```

I need a way to not have this be reversed.  I have tried using the reverse() function but cannot since this is not a list or a tuple.

Comment: What do you mean backwards? Can you share the output?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR the output is the first block of code

Comment: Why do you care about the key order? Terraform is just alphabetically sorting it but that shouldn't matter at all to any YAML parser.

Comment: It matters on how it looks in the repository

Comment: Then instead you'd need to string template (eg [`templatefile`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html) it out which is much more error prone but gives you the exact control you need here if you do really care about key order. I'd question whether you should care about it though. If it's generated by machines and read by machines then it shouldn't matter what order the keys are in for human consumption.